# Conditional Expectation, given $N=n$

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Expanding on this question: [Conditional Probability Given N=n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377814/conditional-probability-given-n-n)

Suppose that $N$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\mu$. Given $N=n$, random variables $X_1, ... X_n$ are independent with uniform (0,1) distribution. So there are a random number of $X$'s.

c) Let $S_n=X_1+...+X_N$ denote the sum of the random number of $X$'s (If $N=0$ then $S_N=0$). Find $P(S_N=0$).

I'm thinking: 
$$P(S_N=0)= P(S_N=0|N=0)\cdot P(N=0)$$
By condition $(N=0) \to (S_N=0):$ $P(S_N=0|N=0)=1$ so $P(S_N=0)$ is exponential distribution for $0$.

How can I carry this part forward to solve d) Find $E(S_N)$
$$E[E(S_N|N=n)]=E(pN)=pE(N)=p\mu$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_N]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[S_N|N]]
$$
Now, $$
\mathbb{E}[S_N|N]
= \mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=1}^N X_n|N]
= \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_n]
= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2} = \frac{N}{2}
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_N]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{N}{2}\right]=\frac{\mu}{2}\,.
$$

**Note:** this is a special case of [compound Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution).

Comment: We can simply use Wald's identity to compute
$$
\mathbb E[S_N] = \mathbb E[N]\mathbb E[X_1] = \frac\mu2.
$$

Comment: Yes. But I didn't want to assume knowledge of [Wald's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) here. It's useful to derive the result at least once by oneself...

Comment: I suppose the law of total expectation is more elementary.

Comment: Well, I'd say so. Without it, conditional expectations become quite unmanageable...

Comment: Thanks - how does $E[X_n]$ become 1/2 - $P(X_1|N=1) \cdot P(N=1) + P(X_1|N=2)\cdot P(X_2|N=2)\cdot P(N=2) + ... \approx 1/2$?

Comment: @ElliottdeLaunay $X_n$ is just a r.v. uniform on $(0,1)$. Its expectation is $1/2$.